# How to find all posts that have an author who is already in the friends array?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to grab all posts from the user's friends list and populate them from newest to oldest.

Controller function to grab all friends posts:

```
async function indexByFriends(req, res) {
  const { handle } = req.user;
  console.log('handle:', handle);
  try {
    const userProfile = await Profile.findOne({ handle });
    console.log('friends handles:', userProfile.friends);

    const posts = await Post.find({ author: { $in: userProfile.friends } })
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
      .populate({
        path: 'author',
        select: '-_id -__v',
        match: { handle: { $in: userProfile.friends } }
      });

    res.json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
}
```

Profile model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const profileSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  photo: String,
  handle: String,
  friends: [{
    type: String,
    ref: 'Profile'
  }],
  friendRequests: [String],
  bio: String,
  followers: [String],
  following: [String],
  blocked: [String],
  verified: Boolean,
  posts: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }],
  restaurants: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Restaurant'
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true,
})

const Profile = mongoose.model('Profile', profileSchema)

export { Profile }
```

Post model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const postSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  photo: String,
  meal: String,
  review: String,
  title: String,
  rating: Number,
  description: String,
  author: { 
    type: String, 
    ref: 'Profile',
    field: 'handle' 
  },
  resturant: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }},{
  timestamps: true,
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)

export { Post }
```

When I run that function I am retunred a 500 error:
`GET /api/posts/friends 500 131.701 ms - 258` as well as `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "SBBGameMaster" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Profile"`

My json data look like this:

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"SBBGameMaster\"",
    "valueType": "string",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "SBBGameMaster",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"SBBGameMaster\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Profile\""
}
```

I understand that the issue is around using the handle instead of the object_id. I want to use the handle to make it easier to look up users based on the handle, instead of having to type the users _id.

I'd expect to see a list of all posts who's author is a handle of a user that is also in the user's friend array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `Post.author` reference declaration to:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
  ...
  author: { 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Profile',
  },
  ...
})
```